# SitecoreContext and Azure Indexes

Tags: azure, sitecore, sitecore8

Currently I'm trying to build a Sitemap using Azure Indexes. When using the Sitecore Context I only get the first 50 results, I need to page through the rest of the results to create my map.

See my current code below:

```
var queryable = searchContext.GetQueryable<GenericSearchItem>();
var results = queryable.GetResults();

 var pagemod = results.TotalSearchResults % 50;
 var pagecount = (results.TotalSearchResults - pagemod) / 50;
 for (int i=0;i<= pagecount+1; i++)
 {        
     var items= queryable.Page(i, 50).ToList();
     foreach (var item in items)
     {
          var dbItem = Sitecore.Context.Database.GetItem(item.ItemId);
          listURl.Add(new UrlDefinition(Sitecore.Links.LinkManager.GetItemUrl(dbItem, options), dbItem.Statistics.Updated));
     }
  }
  return listURl;
```

Is there a better way to do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can use $count, $skip, and $top parameters to do the pagination, for example:

```
GET /indexes/onlineCatalog/docs?search=*$top=15&$skip=0&$count=true
GET /indexes/onlineCatalog/docs?search=*$top=15&$skip=15&$count=true
GET /indexes/onlineCatalog/docs?search=*$top=15&$skip=30&$count=true
```

For more information, please see [paging results](https://aka.ms/paging-results)

Comment: Can you use this with the sitecore context?